# Import Large CSV File into In-Memory DataTable

Tags: vb.net, csv, import, datatable

What is the fastest and most efficient way to import a VERY large CSV file into an in-memory .NET DataTable? As far as the CSV file size, think BIG, use your imagination, and plan on handling out of memory issues etc.

I love the performance when using SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy to import large CSV files into Tables on the DB Server but for this example we are importing into an In-Memory .NET DataTable.

Thanks!

Comment: TextParser in the Visual basic namespace is hugely efficient.

Comment: Why don't you search how to use `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.xx`? Why would you want to load all in memory if you can work with Excel file like database table by issuing Sql statements?

Comment: While the [TextFieldParser class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is useful, there are alternatives which claim to be faster, so you may want to search for some of them and do some testing.